# Properly Creating Postgres RDS db instance "Upgrade" log group in CloudWatch

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to have my postgres db instance export logs to CloudWatch. And checking in the RDS console I see that I am exporting both `upgrade` logs and `postgresql` logs. Do both log streams just come under one log group?

I ask because when looking at my CloudWatch log group console I see that `/aws/rds/instance/test-postgres-db-instance/postgresql` has been properly created. However, I don't see a corresponding `/aws/rds/instance/test-postgres-db-instance/upgrade` log group. And when looking at the `configuration` tab in the RDS console of this db instance, and under the `Published Logs` section - I click on the `upgrade` CloudWatch log link - it tries to send me to a non-existent log group. I even tried upgrading the engine version of the specific instance - yet still no `upgrade` log group was created.

If I look at the other log stream `/aws/rds/instance/test-postgres-db-instance/postgresql` it seems to look like I see my DB shutting down and starting up again which I think makes sense with the upgrade. But I don't see anything explicitly referring to an upgrade in those `postgresql` logs. Am I missing something or not configuring something correctly to get `upgrade` logs group created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution with help of AWS support. `Upgrade` log group is only created once a major upgrade happens (i.e 10.x -> 11.x) / when the [pgupgrade module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgupgrade.html) is invoked. When I tested I only did a minor upgrade (10.x -> 10.y s.t y > x).

Some more detail on what exactly constitutes [major vs. minor upgrade](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_UpgradeDBInstance.Upgrading.html) per AWS RDS as I'm sure I oversimplified it above